# Tweak jQuery highlighting script

Tags: jquery

I got the following jQuery plugin to highlight query keywords in a string. It curretly highlight each query keyword found in the string, both exact word matches but also if the keywords are just a part of a longer word.

In the case of a user typing a query e.g. "I am a human" I would though like to avoid highlighting all the i's and a's in the string. How can I tweak this script to only highlight words of less than 3 chars if the match a whole word?
 I.d. if the highlighting tag is `<b>` the string `"I am a humanoid"` and the keywords are `I am a human` the function would output:

`"<b>I</b> <b>am</b> <b>a</b> <b>human</b>oid"`

instead of currently:

`"<b>I</b> <b>am</b> <b>a</b> <b>human</b>o<b>i</b>d"`

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
 function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
  var skip = 0;
  if (node.nodeType == 3) {
   var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
   if (pos >= 0) {
    var spannode = document.createElement('span');
    spannode.className = 'highlight';
    var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
    var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
    var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
    spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
    middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
    skip = 1;
   }
  }
  else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
   for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
   }
  }
  return skip;
 }
 return this.each(function() {
  innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
 });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't amended the plugin as that belongs to someone and I haven't checked the rights on it - although it's probably free to amend. Instead I created a function for you, which could easily be turned into a plugin if you have the inclination.

If the search term is 3 chars or less, it will only highlight a matching word. Otherwise it will highlight any part of a word.

```
function highlight(original, searchterms) {
    var terms = searchterms.split(" ");
    var output = original;

    for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
        var term = terms[i];
        if (term.length <= 3) {
            // replace whole word only
            var re = new RegExp("\\b" + term + "\\b", "gi");
            output = output.replace(re, "<span class=\"highlight\">" + term + "</span>");
        }
        else {
            // replace any part of word
            var re = new RegExp(term, "gi");
            output = output.replace(re , "<span class=\"highlight\">" + term + "</span>");
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing it working with a couple of demos: http://jsfiddle.net/XNMzg/2/